# How do implement a SignalR heartbeat/ping betweeen ASP.NET and Windows Server service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, signalr

I am needing to implement a heartbeat or ping/test from an ASP.NET Admin page to a Windows Service service. How do I implement a SignalR ping function?
SingalR has a HeartbeatMonitor class with no example of how it could be used:

```
public void Beat(
    TimeSpan timeElapsed
)
```

Comment: There's no example because it's not for you. It's an implementation detail. We send keep alives from the server to the client.

Answer (score 1):

On the server add the following hub:

```
    public class HeartBeatHub: Hub
    {
        public void Heartbeat()
        {
            Clients.All.heartbeat();
        }
    }
```

Add this to your HTML:

```
    <div>
        <div id="hearbeat"></div>
        <input type="button" id="sendHeartBeat" value="Send HB" />
    </div>
```

On your ASP.NET app in JavaScript consume and use the SignalR heartbeat:

```
    $(function () {

        var hearbeat = $.connection.heartBeatHub;

        //Listen for hearbeats from the server
        hearbeat.client.heartbeat = function () {
            var hbeatName = $('<div />').text('Hearbeat Received').html();
            $('#hearbeat').append(hbeatName);
            alert("heartbeat!");
        };

        //Call the server and request a hearbeat
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
          $('#sendHeartBeat').click(function () {
                hearbeat.server.heartbeat();
           });
        });
    });
```